# Creating 3D image from importing 2D images

Tags: syntax, image3d

I'm trying to recreate a 3D image from it's 2D slices. I have saved the 2D images as "image1, image2, etc". I've imported them this way:

```
importlist = 
Table[Import[
 "C:\\ImageSlices\\\
 image" <> ToString[i] <> ".jpg"], {i, 101}]
```

Importing has worked well so far - it is stacking them into a 3D image that is where I am stuck. I'm trying to use the Image3D function in the following ways (unsucessfully):

```
Image3D [{importlist[i], {i, 101}}]

Image3D [{Import[
"C:\\ImageSlices\\\
image" <> ToString[i] <> ".jpg"], {i, 101}}]
```

I will be needing to stack many images into a 3D figure in the future, what is the best way to efficiently do this? I'm stuck on the link between the imported images and the argument for the Image3D function that will properly call them

Comment: The syntax for Image3D is `Image3D[{image1, image2, ...}]`. So try `Image3D[importList]`.

Comment: I tried, it gives me this message:
"Image3D::imgarray: The specified argument importlist should be an array of rank 3 or 4 with machine-sized numbers or a list of images of consistent dimension and color space."

Comment: What does `Dimensions[importList]` give?

Comment: It outputs the following: "{}"